# NestJs Entity Find with where relation not found or get error

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

hi to every one i try to use find or find one and searching existing data on db (postgress), but i taking some i wrong because is getting nothing got this code:

**entitys:**

```
@Entity()
export class invoice {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id?: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Business)
  idorigin: Business;

  @Column({nullable: true})
  txTransacction: string;


  @ManyToOne(() => BusinessInteraction,{ nullable:true })
  businessInteraction: BusinessInteraction;

}

@Entity()
export class BusinessInteraction {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Business)
  Business: Business;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt!: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: false, default: true})
  valid: boolean;
}

@Entity()
export class Business {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true, default: '' })
  businesImgUri?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true, default: 'USD' })
  currency: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt!: Date;
}
```

**and service:**

```
    public async updateInvoice(id: string, status: string, BusinessId: string) {
        try {
          console.log(BusinessId);
          let obj = await this.invoiceRepository.findOne(
            {
              where: {
                id: id,
   //fail with this part, getting undefinted when exist in db
            // businessInteraction: {
            //   Business:{
            //     id: BusinessId
            //   }
            // }
              }, relations: ['method', 'businessInteraction', 'businessInteraction.Business']
            });
          if(!obj) { throw new Error("Invoice not found"); }
          if(obj.businessInteraction.Business.id != BusinessId) {throw new Error("Invoice Not Valid");}
          obj.estatus_invoice = estatus_invoiceEnum[status];
          const res = await this.invoiceRepository.update({ id: id }, obj);
          return obj;
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      }
```

i always tried to use find or findOne with relation or sub relation but it fails, so i like to make sure i don't make a mistake in my knowledge, or if something i'm not adding